# extract index as array after value_counts() from categorical

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Since I started to use `categorical` types in pandas I have a specific piece of code which won't  work: (i formed it as a test for convenience):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["a", "b", "c", "a"]})

df["B"] = df["A"].astype('category')
original_grouped=df["A"].value_counts()
assert(isinstance( original_grouped.index.values, np.ndarray))

b_grouped=df["B"].value_counts()
print(type( b_grouped.index.values))
assert(isinstance( b_grouped.index.values, np.ndarray))
```

How can I convert `b_grouped.index.values` into a `np.ndarray`? after some search, I couldn't find and attributes or set methods to extract it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working [`Series.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html) in pandas 0.25.1 :

```
print(type( b_grouped.index.to_numpy()))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

assert(isinstance( b_grouped.index.to_numpy(), np.ndarray))
```